# Interpreting conditioning on a pre-determined action

Tags: probability

This is a reformulation of a final exam question in a probability course that has me questioning how I convert problem statements to models. It is not the exact problem statement from the exam, but captures the issue. I am not interested in any answers to the problem statement but whether the conversion of "problem statement in English"-->probability model is done correctly.

Problem Statement: A person places an item in a red ball and the red ball into a basket $\Omega$ along with other balls: $R={\text{set of red balls}}$. A set of green balls $G$ is also added to the basket: $\Omega=R\cup G, |R|=K, |\Omega|=n$. Additionally, the number of red balls has a probability of its own where $K-1\sim\text{Bin}(n-1,p)$ and $n=const$. $A$ is the event the item is retrieved. The same person reaches for a red ball. Given they retrieve a red ball, what is the probability they retrieve the item?

To me and quite a few students, the statement "same person reaches for a red ball" implies event $B=$"person retrieved a ball from $R$" is deterministic and no longer random, i.e. model probabilities are $p(B|K)=1,p(B^c|K)=0,$ and $p(A|K)=\frac{1}{K}$, but the published solution for the exam conditioned using $p(B)\neq 1,p(B^c)\neq 0,$ and $p(A)=\frac{1}{n}$. We argued that the wording was confusing and that if the intent was to condition on a non-trivial $p(B)$, then the statement should have been "person reaches for a ball" rather than "person reaches for a red ball". We were nevertheless marked wrong and staff has not responded to our concerns. Other students responded that "given they retrieve a red ball" in the final question implies $p(B)\neq 1$.

It really does not make sense to me that if a person knows the intended result is in a set $R$ and proceeds to search set $R$ that a mutually exclusive set $G$ matters at all.

My question(s):

(1) Is it wrong to interpret "person does $B$" as $p(B)=1$ in this case?

(2) If $p(B)\neq 1$, can anyone explain why a mutually exclusive set $G$ matters or provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, one would think that a person who "reaches for a red ball" is pretty near certain to actually get a red ball.  The green balls are, pardon the expression, a red herring.  Given that the person retrieved a red ball, and that each
red ball is equally likely to be the one retrieved, the probability of getting the ball containing the item is indeed $1/K$.  The only way to have $p(A) = 1/n$ would be if
the person was making a random choice from the whole set of balls, but there's no indication of that from what you wrote: "reaches for a red ball" would seem to imply a conscious choice to take a red ball rather than a green one.